# Unix TimeStamp conversion into Date/Time field failed in Airflow DAG

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, airflow

I am trying to convert Unix Timestamp into Date/Time format in Airflow Dag .

Function **get_execution_time()** in below Airflow script throwing parsing error :-

```
ERROR - HTTP error: Bad Request
[2021-10-04 21:39:46,187] ERROR - {"error":"unable to parse: metric parse error: expected field at 1:94: \"model_i7,model_owner=cgrm_developer,model_name=m1,execution_time=**<function get_execution_time at 0x7f46df0b1b70>\**""}
[2021-10-04 21:39:46,216] ERROR - 400:Bad Request
```

Parser failed to resolve the unix timestamp into Date/Time format and throwing `execution_time=<function get_execution_time at 0x7f46df0b1b70>\`  .

Here is the executable script :-

```
from airflow import DAG
from random import random, seed, choice
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
import time
import warnings
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from functools import wraps

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)


def get_execution_time():
    ts = int("1284101485")
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    

model_list = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4']
def get_data_str(model_name):
    table_name = 'model_i7,'
    execution_time=get_execution_time()
    parameters = ',model_name={model_name},execution_time={execution_time}'.format(\
    model_name=model_name,execution_time=get_execution_time)
    return table_name + 'model_owner=test_developer' + parameters   


default_args = {
    'owner': 'developer',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021,10,04),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'catchup' : False,
    'dagrun_timeout' : timedelta(hours=3),
    'email_on_success': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False

}

with DAG(
    dag_id='testi7',
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['testi7'],
    access_control = {'developer':{'can_dag_read','can_dag_edit'}},
    default_args=default_args 
) as dag:

    for model_name in model_list:
        extracting_metrics = SimpleHttpOperator(
            task_id='extracting_metrics',
            http_conn_id ='metrics_api',
            endpoint='/write',
            python_callable=get_data_str,
            provide_context=True,
            data=get_data_str(model_name)
)
```

Expected Output :-

| table_name | model_owner | model_name | execution_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| model_output | developer | model1 | 2010-09-10T10:59:33+00:00 |

Would appreciate it if some one can help to resolve above exception .

Comment: Why do you want to create tasks based on `choice`? which is a random generated value?

Comment: Also your code will not run. You are doing some mix between `PythonOperator` and `SimpleHttpOperator`. Please update your code to a minimal reproduce example.

Comment: Thanks @Elad for your suggestion . I have refactored the code and now getting parser error when trying to call function in Airflow DAG . Throwing below error : ERROR - HTTP error: Bad Request [2021-10-04 21:39:46,187] ERROR - {"error":"unable to parse: metric parse error: expected field at 1:94: "model_i7,model_owner=cgrm_developer,model_name=m1,execution_time=<function get_execution_time at 0x7f46df0b1b70>""}